# FileSystemAPI not working for directory containing large no of files?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, native-file-system-api-js

I am using below code which uses FileSystemAPI with webworker

```
const worker = new Worker( "worker.js" );
btn.onclick = async (evt) => {
  const dirHandle = await showDirectoryPicker();
  worker.postMessage( dirHandle );
};
worker.onmessage = (evt) => {
  console.log( evt.data );
  document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify( evt.data, (key, value) => {
    if( value instanceof Blob ) {
      return { name: value.name, size: value.size, type: value.type };
    }
    return value;
  }, 4 );
}
```

**worker.js**

```
onmessage = async (evt) => {
  const out = {};
  const dirHandle = evt.data;  
  await handleDirectoryEntry( dirHandle, out );
  postMessage( out );
};
async function handleDirectoryEntry( dirHandle, out ) {
  for await (const entry of dirHandle.values()) {
    if (entry.kind === "file"){
      const file = await entry.getFile();
      out[ file.name ] = file;
    }
    if (entry.kind === "directory") {
      const newHandle = await dirHandle.getDirectoryHandle( entry.name, { create: false } );
      const newOut = out[ entry.name ] = {};
      await handleDirectoryEntry( newHandle, newOut );
    }
  }
}
```

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/navigate-sub-directory-from-a-worker?path=worker.js%3A5%3A21

Above working working for small dataset but with directory with more than 1000+ files it's not working.

Any help or input appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my glitch to show some kind of "progress" witness. Do you see it stuck on your machine? Personally I am able to show the entire [WPT project](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/) tree, even though it takes some time. Btw, better link to the standalone page (https://navigate-sub-directory-from-a-worker.glitch.me/), crossorigin iframes can't use this API.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and I just successfully had it traverse 1K+ files on my machine (MacBook Pro 2020). If you run into this problem again, please file a [new.crbug.com](https://new.crbug.com/) (using this link pre-populates the bug with all the info the engineering team will need). Feel free to post the bug ID here and I'm happy to triage.